# Conditions about $A$ for $\|Ax\|_2 \leq \|x\|_2$ to be true

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, projection

Suppose $A$ is a projection. What are the conditions that $A$ needs to satisfy for

$\|Ax\|_2 \leq \|x\|_2$ to hold.

Two possibilities I can see are:

- $A$ is an orthogonal projection.
- The largest singular value of $A$ is less than or equal to 1.

Are there any other specific conditions on $A$ which satisfy this?

Comment: Have you written down a **non**-orthogonal projection and checked to see whether the condition holds? I'd suggest something like $\pmatrix{1 & a \\ 0 & 0}$ for some small value of $a > 0$.

Comment: Are you looking for this to hold for one $x$ or every $x$?

Answer (score 1):

Your statement implies that the space must be contracting. Since $A$ can be decomposed via SVD, then the only necessary condition for this, I believe, is that the largest singular value be less than or equal to 1.

Answer (score 1):

HINT:

Recall that $A$ is a projection. Let $u\in \textrm{Im} A$, $v \in \textrm{Ker} A$.  We have $A(u+\epsilon v) = u$.  Therefore 
$$\|u+ \epsilon v \|\ge \|u\|$$
for all $\epsilon \in \mathbb{R} $ (or $\mathbb{C}$).

This implies $\langle u, v\rangle = 0$.

We conclude that $A$ must be an orthogonal projection.

Comment: Thanks. But there can be oblique projections which might satisfy this inequality for some $x$ right?

Comment: @shani:  yes, it may happen for some $x$.  In the case of real coefficients,  say if it works for $x = u+v$, it may not work for $x ' = u-v$ ( draw a picture in 2d with some triangles).

Answer (score 1):

As you stated $\lVert Ax \rVert_2 \leq \lVert x \rVert_2, \forall x \iff \bar{\sigma}(A) \leq 1$ where $\bar{\sigma}$ denotes the largest singular value. If $A$ is orthogonal then $\lVert Ax \rVert_2 = \lVert x \rVert_2, \forall x$. These conditions have nothing to do with $A$ being a projection and applies to all matrices.